# Referencig values in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector and would like to extract element 3 and 4. Can you please help me understand what the logic is behind the code version without parenthesis? I appreciate your help.

```
a=c(1:5)
a[(2+1): 4]    # with parenthesis, makes sense
[1] 3 4
a[ 2+1 : 4]    # without parenthesis,  what is the logic here?
[1]  3  4  5 NA
```

Comment: First comes the vector `1:4`, then add `2` to each of its elements.

Comment: Why not type `2+1 : 4` in the console and see what you get? Much quicker than bothering to type a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The `:` operator is evaluated before the `+` operator.
Consider

```
print(c(2+1:4))
```

This returns

```
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

Because a vector 1,2,3,4 is created, then all elements are added by 2.

[R Operator Syntax and Precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html)
gives an overview over the priority of R's operators. The sequence operator `:` comes before the arithmetic operators like `+` or `-`.